# Syntax error trying to average variables

Tags: ocaml

I'm just starting out trying to learn OCaml. I wrote a function to take two floats and return their average, but I'm getting a syntax error.

```
let average a b =
  (a +. b) /. 2.0;;

print_float (average 5.0 -5.0);;
```

The stated error is

```
This expression has type float -> float but an expression was expected of type int.
```

and there's a line underlining "average 5.0". OCaml is version 4.01.0 and system is ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just trying things out here. By looking at your code and trying it on an online compiler, I get the following results.

```
# let average a b =
#   (a +. b) /. 2.0;;
val average : float -> float -> float = <fun>
# average 5.0 6.0;;
- : float = 5.5
# average 5.0 -6.0;;
File "", line 1, characters 0-11:
Error: This expression has type float -> float
       but an expression was expected of type int
#
```

The error is thrown when one of the values is a negative float. Please check in that direction.

Comment: This was the reason. The minus sign is being interpreted as the minus operator. Therefore it was thinking I wanted to subtract 5.0 from average 5.0. The solution is to put the negative number in parentheses i.e. print_float(average 5.0 (-5.0));;

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid extra parentheses you can use the unary floating negation operator `~-.`

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let average a b =
  (a +. b) /. 2.0;;
val average : float -> float -> float = <fun>
# print_float (average 5.0  ~-. 5.0);;
0.- : unit = ()
#
```

However, this operator is so clumsy looking that I've never seen it in real code. So you need to use parentheses with negative numbers sometimes.

I did some reading and experimentation and wrote up a description of all the operators for subtraction and negation: [Unary minus and floating point number in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984661/unary-minus-and-floating-point-number-in-ocaml/8990423?s=26%7C0.1715#8990423)